# what is the [0] doing in this code?

Tags: powershell

I have taken over some code from someone that has left and am wondering what the [0] means in the below code that the previous person wrote?

I mean, he wrote this:

```
$os = (Get-WmiObject -computername $hostfqdn -class Win32_OperatingSystem -credential $credential)
$ostitle   = @($os)[0].Caption+" SP"+@($os)[0].ServicePackMajorVersion+"."+@($os)[0].ServicePackMinorVersion
```

But, if I try the below I get the same result as if I add a [0] in?

```
PS C:\> $os = (Get-WmiObject -computername SERVER-class Win32_OperatingSystem)
PS C:\> @($os)[0].Caption
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
```

With a [0]:

```
PS C:\> @($os).Caption
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
```

The entire function is:

```
function getoperatingsystem([string]$hostfqdn, [object]$credential, [int]$serverid)
    {
        try {    
            $os = (Get-WmiObject -computername $hostfqdn -class Win32_OperatingSystem -credential $credential)
            $ostitle   = @($os)[0].Caption+" SP"+@($os)[0].ServicePackMajorVersion+"."+@($os)[0].ServicePackMinorVersion
            UpdateRecord "UPDATE t_server SET os='$ostitle' WHERE serverid=$serverid"
        } catch [Exception] {
            $errmsg = $error[0]        
            $currentuser = [Environment]::UserName
            $datetimestamp  = get-date
            writelog "$datetimestamp,$currentuser,[getoperatingsystem],$hostfqdn,$errmsg"
            $error.clear()
            return $false
        }
    }
```

Comment: @() is an array, [0] gets you the item with the index 0 in your array so for example for the array `@(1,2)` `$(1,2)[0]` -> 1, `$(1,2)[1]` -> 2 if your array only has 1 item it doesnt matter

Comment: Maybe it is an array subscript and handles the case where multiple operating systems are installed on a machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@($os)[0]` Means he is creating an array on the fly, with one element, and he is accessing the array's first element with `[0]` (its index in the array).

He should just have used `$os`

Comment: Yes thought of that, but that specific WMI is requesting the OS running on a particular system.

Comment: true for that particular case